# PC turns off after hours

Tags: windows-7, shutdown, hardware-failure

I have a PC with I7 Processor, 4GB RAM, GTX480, 700 WATT Power Supply.

**1)** The computer after some hours shuts down by it self. Not normal shutdown. It just turns off. After this failure it opens again by itself.

**2)** After hours if PC has not yet turn off unexcpectedly. I experience "lagging" in every game i play. The problem is solved when i restart my computer.

**Things i did:**

**1)** I've changed Power Supply.

**2)** I cleaned the PC Tower.

**Note:**
*The quality of my Speakers is very bad. I report this because with these bad quality speakers i hear electricity sounds. For example when i play a game sometimes i hear a "zzzzzzzzzzzz" from the speakers. Seconds before my PC turn off i hear a more intense "zzzzzzzzzz" from the speakers. So i always know that the PC is going to turn off 3-4 seconds before it happens.*

**Note 2:** *I fear that is a CPU or Motherboard problem. And if it is, i will throw it from the window.. The machine is less than 1 year old and expensive enough...*

Comment: Log the temperature and see if it is the normal range.

Comment: Also check the warranty.